# CommandArgument on SQLDatasource Inserted?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I'm wishing to redirect to two different pages depending on which button is pressed on my form.

Both buttons call the Insert method of the Datasource, but only one of them needs to get hold of the newly inserted GUID and redirect using that GUID.

I'm doing it using this code

```
Protected Sub DSCustomers_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles DSCustomers.Inserted
        Response.Redirect("~/addTicket.aspx?step=2&customerID=" & e.Command.Parameters("@customerID").Value.ToString)
End Sub
```

But how can I know if it's the other button that has been pressed and doesn't need to redirect?

I can't get access to the CommandArgument otherwise I would just check which button has been pressed using that and then redirect accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use a global private boolean?

```
Dim RedirectButtonPressed As Boolean = false

Protected Sub RedirectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RedirectButton.Clicked
    // code code code
    RedirectButtonPressed = True
End Sub

Protected Sub DSCustomers_Inserted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles DSCustomers.Inserted
    If RedirectButtonPressed Then
        Response.Redirect("~/addTicket.aspx?step=2&customerID=" & e.Command.Parameters("@customerID").Value.ToString)
        RedirectButtonPressed = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great, didn't think about doing that at all!  So easy!  Cheers Joel